# React Native : target with hash string 'android-X' not found

Tags: android, react-native, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to develop my first [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) `Android` app. When I run

```
sudo react-native run-android
```

I get the following error

```
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.981 secs
Could not install the app on the device, see the error above.
```

I have `24.3.3` under `/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk` with all API-23 packages installed

[image]

My `android/app/build.gradle` says

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.awesomeandroid"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```

When I try `$ANDROID_HOME`, it says `-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3: is a directory`.

I have also added `local.properties` under `android/app/` and added `sdk.dir=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to how to do this? I am having the exact same problem and have tried everything without avail. Please have a look at my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778085/unable-to-build-react-native-app-on-android-device-failed-to-find-target-with-h) and help if you can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to point **ANDROID_HOME** to the parent directory of **platforms** and **platform-tools** so **/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk**

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to how to do this? I am having the exact same problem and have tried everything without avail. Please have a look at my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778085/unable-to-build-react-native-app-on-android-device-failed-to-find-target-with-h) and help if you can.

Comment: @Frosty619 One of the things that threw me off was that I was working in Android Studio and I assumed that the SDK files would be saved in the same directory as the Studio files. Not so, and even though the SDK Path is listed right on top of the SDK Manager, I missed it completely.

Answer (score 12):

Your $ANDROID_HOME should point to `/usr/local/android-sdk` and it would be the parent directory of platforms and platform-tools

Gradle will try to locate tools dir in the following location: `$ANDROID_HOME/platform/android-23` so verify that you have your tools installed there if the android-23 folder is not present inside $ANDROID_HOME/platform/ , please install Android 6.0 (API23)

Comment: Which part of my answer have you tried? Have you verified that `$ANDROID_HOME/platform/android-23` exists?

Comment: how come they point to different locations (24.3.3 and android-23)?

Comment: if you are unable to find android-23 try installing the Android 6.0 (API 23) Update via SDK manager

Answer (score 3):

What I did was to change the target my application was compiled against. To do this edit the file `android/app/build.gradle` on your project and modify the following:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
```

This should match whatever you have installed without requiring to download another API version.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to change the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` dependency to the right version (which I found [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).

Comment: Also, take into account that you'll be doing this for any library that requires any platform build to happen.

Answer (score 0):

please try to install android 6.0 (Marshmallow) api level 23

i just did and works for me

[image: android 6.0 (Marshmallow) api level 23]

Answer (score 0):

I followed the React Native Getting Started instructions and my ANDROID_HOME and PATH was right but I was still getting this error.

The solution was to install "Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)" from this screen (without clicking "Show Package Details"):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem，and just replaced `export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk` by `export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1`

[android sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFXg9.png)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me, working on a react native app generated with Ignite. Finally, I opened the project up in Android Studio, instead of doing everything via the command line, and a bunch of errors popped up. Fixing the errors one by one within Android Studio solved this problem for me.

You do need the correct path set for ANDROID_HOME for this to work. I installed android sdk with brew, so my path was `/usr/local/opt/android-sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me - I've just removed all installed SDK Platforms and SDK tools using Android SDK Tool

[image: Android SDK Tool]

And Run build again and Android Studio found what it should install and where. If you will follow this instruction - make sure you are running Android Studio with enough permissions to install everything.

Have fun with this issue! Hope it will help you