# Running React-Native App locally (FB F8 App) - Build Failed Error

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to run a the react-native app that was used at F8 locally.  I am following the instructions here: http://makeitopen.com/tutorials/building-the-f8-app/local-setup/

I have everything work correctly (I can go to http://localhost:8080/dashboard/apps and http://localhost:8080/graphql and see data and run queries)

However, when I try to run the builds for iOS and Android, I am running into errors.

Android Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/thisuser/f8app/android/app/build.gradle' line: 124

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 4.006 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

iOS Error:

```
=== BUILD TARGET CodePush OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/thisuser/f8app/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-fbsdk.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTConvert+FBSDKSharingContent.o /Users/thisuser/f8app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/iOS/RCTFBSDK/share/RCTConvert+FBSDKSharingContent.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
/Users/thisuser/f8app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F8v2.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:464:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:484:13)
    at _runIOS (/Users/thisuser/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:82:32)
    at /Users/thisuser/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:24:5
    at tryCallTwo (/Users/thisuser/f8app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
    at doResolve (/Users/thisuser/f8app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
    at new Promise (/Users/thisuser/f8app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
    at Array.runIOS (/Users/thisuser/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:23:10)
    at Object.run (/Users/thisuser/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:96:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:88:7)
```

How do I make these work?

Answer (score 0):

#### For android only

You will need to set `Android SDK path` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36787719/2955679) and must have at least `Android SDK Build-Tools Rev 23.0.1`.

Comment: how do I find my Android SDK path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x/19986294#19986294 for mac.

Comment: hmm so I set this up and updated my bash, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Open `Android SDK Manager` when `android` command run in terminal?

Comment: you mean Android Studio?

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  Why is it telling me this: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Comment: No, `command prompt` or `terminal` run `android` command will show only SDK Manager will open, it's your `$ANDROID_HOME` path is ok.

Comment: when I run this, it shows: asdasd-MacBook-Pro-2:f8app asdasd$ android
-bash: android: command not found

Comment: that's when I run it from that f8app folder, but when I run it from ~, it opens the Android SDK manager

Comment: any ideas what may be going on?