# Ubuntu / Elementary OS cannot set ANDROID_HOME

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

I'm facing the problem, that i cannot set the ANDROID_HOME path variable.

I added the following lines to my bashrc file:

```
# Android Path
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk/Sdk/tools
```

But when i try to access android via the terminal i get this error:

```
android: command not found
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Is the directory really named `Sdk` with a captial S?

Comment: you can check if variable is set by entering **echo $ANDROID_HOME**

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://andriod.stackexchange.com OR http://askubuntu.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the variable in your PATH as well. The aim is for your PATH variable to contain the complete folder path, in which the file 'android' is present.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk/Sdk/tools
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME:$PATH
```

Don't forget to source your bashrc after adding these lines

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Again, the file 'android' should be present in the tools folder.

Comment: I believe the proper way to set the path is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36787719/106704

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

1)Open the bashrc file from command line

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

2) Add following lines at the top.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

3)Now, quit terminal and re-launch, and try typing:

```
adb -h
android -h
```

If both commands are giving you output, it means everything works fine.